# Dynamically call a label in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, label

I am trying to call a label dynamically but have no idea how to do it.

I want to make a label visible depending on the integer.

So if `int i = 1`, then `label1` should turn visible and if `i = 2`, then `label2` should turn visible, and so on and so forth.

How do I do this?

```
int i = word.indexOf("t");
//This is where I need the label to be dynamically called
```

I tried `("label" + i.ToString()).Visible = true;"` in a lazy attempt.

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a dynamic solution:

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
    label.Visible = (label.Name == "label" + i);
```

Note that:

1. this will hide all labels that are not named `"label" + i`. You may need additional filtering logic if there are any other labels on the form/container
2. the above code works if the labels are direct descendants of the form. If that's not the case (for example, the labels are children of a panel called `panel1`), then you'll need to replace `Controls` with `panel1.Controls`

Answer (score 0):

Label1.Visible = (i == 1); // if i is not 1, then label1 is not visible